# Kerberos delegation doesn't work in chrome

Tags: security, google-chrome, iis-7, kerberos

I have an IIS 7 server with 2 sites - site1, site2.

site1 binds port 80, site2 binds port 81.

I have a web page in site2 which sends an http get request via `$.ajax()` to a URL in site1.

I've configured both site to use kerberos:

1. Enabled only windows authentication, selected only negotiate:kerberos in providers.
2. Configured SPN for the user/server in AD.

I use fiddler to monitor the request headers.

1. When I use IE8, I see that kerberos ticket is delegated from site2 to site1 via 2-hop, the way kerberos should work.
2. When I use chrome, I see that keberos ticket is not delegated. I get an 401 error.

I tried setting:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*"
```

...(and specifically the server name), but it has not worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*" helped me.

Comment: I was having difficulties getting [AuthServerWhitelist](https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthServerWhitelist) to work and it seems like Chrome now uses `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` for everything instead of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Chromium`. With `...\Google\Chrome\AuthServerWhitelist` set as `*.example.com` negotiate/Kerberos works as one would expect.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the same registry value to this key to make everything work:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Chromium`

Also interesting to note that I'm using *.domain.local instead of just *.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this in 2022. Chrome changed the registry keys, what was Whitelist is no Allowlist. WhiteList no longer used

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#noNonIncl

Answer (score 0):

Does the value you entered have the quotes in it?

Try entering `*` with no quotes.

Shut down Chrome entirely (check task manager to make sure) and then try again.

If you use `"*"` with the quotes it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Given we now have Edge Chromium. Running the registry script below will fix for both browsers

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist"="*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*"

I extracted both keys from my registry where they have no quotes around * in the registry, however the extracted keys look exactly as I have Posted above

Answer (score 0):

It worked only after I added AuthServerWhitelist key in qouple with  AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist key.

My registry script now looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome] 
"AuthServerWhitelist"="*"
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*"
```